# Creating a git Patch in eclipse across commits

Tags: eclipse, git, patch, egit

I'm using git via the Eclipse [egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin. I am new at using git as my VCS and was wondering if there was a way to create a patch that captures the changes across multiple commits from within Eclipse. For example:

1. Work on a new feature
2. Commit work
3. Fix a bug
4. Commit work
5. Create patch of code added since #1

Can this be done from within eclipse using egit? If not, what is the command line for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git command you're looking for is:

```
git diff HEAD~2 HEAD
```

`HEAD` means your current commit, and `~2` means "two commits before".

I'm not sure if egit can do this, but I'd look for some sort of arbitrary diff functionality: "diff against... [commit]".