# Create patch from multiple Git commits in IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using Git with IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, and I want to create a single patch from multiple consecutive commits in my repository. However, the "Create Patch" button is greyed out as soon as I select more than one commit.

I've tried the command line method as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005131/creating-a-git-patch-in-eclipse-across-commits), and it works great. But is there a way to do it in IDEA's GUI?  I think I should be able to do this *somehow*, since the tooltip says "Create Patch for selected revision(s)".

Answer (score 1):

[Issue IDEA-106422](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106422) reports it is possible, but your problem could be linked to a setting.
What follows applies for `git cherry`, but check if it does for `git patch` as well.

> It is possible. Just select several revisions and click the "Cherry" button.
>   Note that unless you've enabled `Settings | Version Control | Git | "commit automatically on cherry-pick"`, you'll be prompted to review & commit each cherry-pick one by one. Maybe this is what confuses you?

Comment: I enabled that setting and cherry-picked several revisions. It worked and committed all of them automatically to the other branch. However, Create Patch remains grayed out.

Comment: @325is so I suspect the answer was for the `git cherry` only, and git patch is still waiting supporting multiple selection.